# Split vector in a list using sapply and char in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, sapply

this is my vector:

```
nms.new<-c("ABEV3.BBAS3", "ABEV3.BBAS3.new", "ABEV3.BRAP4", "ABEV3.BRAP4.new", 
"ABEV3.BRKM5", "ABEV3.BRKM5.new", "ABEV3.CSAN3", "ABEV3.CSAN3.new", 
"ABEV3.CSNA3", "ABEV3.CSNA3.new", "ABEV3.CYRE3", "ABEV3.CYRE3.new", 
"ABEV3.DTEX3", "ABEV3.DTEX3.new", "ABEV3.ELPL4", "ABEV3.ELPL4.new", 
"ABEV3.EVEN3", "ABEV3.EVEN3.new", "ABEV3.FIBR3", "ABEV3.FIBR3.new", 
"ABEV3.GGBR4", "ABEV3.GGBR4.new", "ABEV3.GOAU4", "ABEV3.GOAU4.new", 
"ABEV3.HYPE3", "ABEV3.HYPE3.new", "ABEV3.JBSS3", "ABEV3.JBSS3.new")
```

I want to split this vector and the result would be something like this:

```
    $`ABEV3.BBAS3`
    [1] "ABEV3.BBAS3"     "ABEV3.BBAS3.new"

    $`ABEV3.BRAP4`
    [1] "ABEV3.BRAP4"     "ABEV3.BRAP4.new"

    $ABEV3.BRKM5
    [1] "ABEV3.BRKM5"     "ABEV3.BRKM5.new"

    $ABEV3.CSAN3
    [1] "ABEV3.CSAN3"     "ABEV3.CSAN3.new"

    $ABEV3.CSNA3
    [1] "ABEV3.CSNA3"     "ABEV3.CSNA3.new"

    $ABEV3.CYRE3
    [1] "ABEV3.CYRE3"     "ABEV3.CYRE3.new"

    $ABEV3.DTEX3
    [1] "ABEV3.DTEX3"     "ABEV3.DTEX3.new"
.
.
.
.
.
```

I tried this:

```
nms.new <- nms.new[sapply(nms.new, nchar) > 6]
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` and `gsub` instead

```
> split(nms.new, gsub("\\.new$", "", nms.new))
$ABEV3.BBAS3
[1] "ABEV3.BBAS3"     "ABEV3.BBAS3.new"

$ABEV3.BRAP4
[1] "ABEV3.BRAP4"     "ABEV3.BRAP4.new"

$ABEV3.BRKM5
[1] "ABEV3.BRKM5"     "ABEV3.BRKM5.new"

$ABEV3.CSAN3
[1] "ABEV3.CSAN3"     "ABEV3.CSAN3.new"
...
```